# Zend Framework partialLoop with associative array of models

Tags: php, zend-framework, partial-views

I'm making a web application in Zend Framework. I've reached the stage of *cleaning up*. As things often go, I have a couple of messy view scripts that have become utterly unreadable (tons of `(v)sprintf`'s and loops).

There's one view that's an absolute nightmare... (no/inaccurate comments, shorthand... all things considered to be mortal sins). Just an example:

```
$rows[$c] .= '<div>'.sprintf('<select id="%s" name="%1$s">',$t.'['.$ref->getCode().']').str_replace('>'.$ref->getCValue().'<',' selected="selected">'.$ref->getCValue().'<','<option>'.implode('</option><option>',$this->vals['P']).'</option>').'</select></div>';
```

In this particular case, I have an array of models that looks like this:

```
$arr = array('FOO'=> $Mylib_Model_Person,'BAR'=> $Mylib_Model_Person2);//1~50 mdls
```

I would like to use a partial loop, but there's a problem:

```
$this->partialLoop('controller/_myPartial.phtml',array('model'=>$arr));
//in the partial loop:
Zend_Debug::dump($this->m);
```

I see all my models correctly, but their keys have all been turned into properties.

```
$this->FOO->someMethod();//works fine
```

Bur I want it to be:

```
<span><?php echo $key; ?></span><span><?php echo $model->someMethod(); ?></span>
```

I've also tried using `$this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('Mylib_Model_Person');`, but that didn't seem to make any difference, other then confuse me.

The only solutions I see is either `array_map`, but that would defeat the point (I'm trying to end up with a clean view script); or rewrite a part of my service layer, to return the data ready structured, and keep the `array_map` there.

I can't help thinking that what I want to do, essentially use a partialLoop as an `array_map` callback, is possible. If it isn't, is there an alternative? Any thoughts?

I've tried `get_object_properties($this)`, and iterate through the object properties, to no avail, the loop simply doesn't get executed(?!)

---

As it turns out `$this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('Mylib_Model_Person');` should have been `$this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('model');`. If I do change this, and start the partial loop by dumping `$this->model`, I see my model. However:

```
echo $this->model->someMethod(); //throws error: method on non-object
Zend_Debug::dump(get_class_methods($this->model));//shows all methods, including someMethod()
```

And to add insult to injury, tears and confusion. The model implements the toArray-thing, so I tried:

```
echo $this->model['someData'];//Error: cannot use object of type Mylib_Model_Person as array!!
```

So, it's not an object when I try to use methods, it's an object when trying to access data as an array, and when using the magic getter method (`$this->model->some_Data`) it doesn't do anything. No errors, but no output either. The view is rendered as is.

---

---

I'm thinking I ran into a bug. I'll rapport it. Consider this:

```
$methods = get_class_methods($this->model);
while($m = array_shift($methods))
{
    if (substr($m,0,3) === 'get')
    {
        Zend_Debug::dump($m);//e.g getName
        Zend_Debug::dump($this->model->{$m}());//'Foobar'
        $m = 'someMethod';//copy-paste, so typo's aren't to blame
        Zend_Debug::dump($this->model->{$m}());//'the data I was after'
    }
}
```

So that works, but the, if I try:

```
$this->model->{'someMethod'}();//Error again
//or even:
$m = 'someMethod';
echo $this->model->{$m}();//Error...
```

That can't be right

Comment: What's `$Mylib_Model_Person`, could you var_dump it?

Comment: It's just an object, just I expected it to be. The loops I wrote myself are working just fine, the data is correct. I just can't seem to get that partialLoop to behave...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. Our development server used to be set up *better* in terms of error reporting:
I assumed `E_ALL | E_STRICT`, but I had a look only to find it changed to a cruddy `E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR`. Seeing as some values in the array can be `false` rather then an object, at some point in the partialLoop script, a notice should have been raised - with the correct ini settings, of course.

That was the cause of the unexpected behaviour; that, and a silly bug or two.